# Path to python.exe

Tags: python, lua

I created a script for hundreds of users. It includes this line:

```lua
os.execute("C:\\InstallPython\\python.exe "Path-to-current-folder-with-python-script")
```

This line is written in Lua language, but language doesn't matter.

User can install Python in any folder. It might be on Disc C or D. I don't know this.
How to create a universal version that suits all users?
Maybe I can get the path to python.exe by a program?

Comment: if python include in PATH then just find it I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this: https://www.lua.org/pil/22.2.html

Usually path to python is in `PYTHON_PATH` environment variable.
So you can try this in your Lua script before running the python script:

```lua
os.getenv("PYTHON_PATH")
```

Once you print this variable, you can see that it indeed includes the path where python was installed, the only thing you might do, is to add a `python.exe` to this string, as it might point to a directory, not to the python executable.

In my case `PYTHON_PATH` value is: `C:\Python27\` when using Python2.7

Comment: Thank You. I accept your answer as solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

sys.executable
```

Above should return the path to the executable.
[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable)

Comment: My problem should be solved BEFORE starting python script. Lua script calls python. It needs path to python.exe